# Adding a non stable release of a project to another maven project

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project where I add the dependencies for the flink libraries as follows:

```
    <repositories>
       <repository>
          <id>apache.snapshots</id>
          <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
          <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
      </repository>
   </repositories>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
          <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
          <version>${flink.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
          <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.10</artifactId>
          <version>${flink.version}</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

I have to switch to the upcoming version of these libraries which is not released in Maven yet.

https://github.com/apache/flink provides the source code and instructions on how to build it but I am relatively unsure how do I linked the compiled projects to my maven project.

Comment: Just build the project and install it to your local repository `mvn clean install`. Then you can have a dependency like usual.

Answer (score 2):

- Build, install to the local repo or deploy to you central repo (if you have one).
- Use the snapshot version (like `1.2-SNAPSHOT`).